# "Save as" an open file from Command Line

Tags: powershell, cmd, converters

I have a *large* folder of DWG files and want to convert them to DXF files, using Solid Edge. After opening the documents, is it possible to "Save As" from the command line or powershell?

Is this a program by program line of code or is it universal for all programs?
So if I wanted to save a .docx document open in Microsoft Word as a .pdf (for want of a better example) can I use that same line of code?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: No, it would not be universal. Word uses Word commands specifically for doing a *save as*, as would any other software. You need code specific to the software that is performing the operation. Word and Excel code would be very similar (as they are both based on VBA), but would not be identical.

Comment: there is a way to kinda-sorta do that. [*grin*] use one of the GUI automation utils like `AutoIT` or `AutoHotKey` to control the gui [selecting menus, clicking buttons, etc.]. the 1st of those has a powershell module that is supposed to be rather good.

Comment: you said _after opening_. did you mean after editing?

Comment: @somebadhat No, only after having opened, simply to convert them to DXF...I don't want to have to pay anything for new software, and I already own Solid Edge

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Righto, thanks for that...I'll look into those if nothing else works tho

Comment: It does, but only from a .dft file, not from DWG (see here: https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/solidedge/Translating-Solid-Edge-Files-from-the-Command-Line/ )...so basically I open up the file, save as a .dft, then convert to dxf...lengthy I know...but it is also helping me get some coding practice in :P

Comment: No command will work in every program ever written.

Comment: @Poyda - you are quite welcome! glad to kinda-sorta help ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented beneath my question,

> No, it would not be universal

So, no, there is no way of using a single command "save as" on every single program, and as Solid Edge doesn't have a command line API, that I know of, I would have to write a program for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well since you want to convert from one Autocad format to another, you could do it using Autocad's command line.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/downloads/caas/downloads/content/autodesk-customization-conversion-tools.html?_ga=2.88877275.1703552679.1574826072-7420195.1574826072

This does require you writing all of the scripting of course.

Alternatively, there is this handy scripted mass converter someone wrote using lisp and they wrote a custom script executor wrapper thingy but their scripting supposedly requires the full version of autocat (at least version 2010 to accomplish this.)

https://www.cadtutor.net/forum/topic/51941-autocad-mass-convert-dwg-to-dxf-batch-convert-dwg-to-dxf-mas-dwg-convert/

That said the official AutocCAD conversion command-line utilities are also going to use LISP scripting, so you might want to just take the second script, and work through it manually testing against the normal AutoCAD utilities until you can get it working for your needs to sort of jump start you.

If you do that I would suggest re-posting with tags for LISP and AutoCAD and give them a sample of what you have got if you end up going the official tools and your own or jump-started script route.

Hope that will be helpful to you and others in the future! :)